# How do I use ReactJs with an existing project that uses EJS Express Mongodb as stack?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sails.js, ejs

- The file structure is based on sailsjs structure, we don't use sailsjs though, this is how it looks like:

  [image]
- Stack used is : EJS Express/Node MongoDb.
- I want to move a certain page from ejs to ReactJS and also implement Webpack with it.
- Is there a way I can convert this into a react app, or simply use react with ejs ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use try react cdn links as script tags.
https://reactjs.org/docs/cdn-links.html